# where does /static/js folder come from?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm new to React, just a question on the bundle js files produced by webpack.
Currently when I I run my app, and I check chrome dev tool, I found  `0.chunk.js`, `bundle.js`, `main.chunk.js` are under `localhost/static/js`, I don't have static folder in my react app, so where does /static/js folder come from? was it create by chrome?

Comment: do you started app with `npm start`?

Comment: @Hameda169 yes, I used npm start

Comment: So, you are using react development server. It serves all files itself. Before serving, it creates all needed files that is not visible and they are created with your code. If you build your app, this JS files will be created by your code and you can see them in build directory

Answer (score 3):

Those files are generated by webpack.
To specify, you can run command `npm run eject` then you can see a folder named `scripts`.

In this folder, first let's check file `start.js` where run when you run `npm start`.

```
const devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, serverConfig);
```

It using WebpackDevServer create a dev server run on your local to host your app, so you can access app through `localhost:3000`. Next let's check `compiler` parameter.

```
const compiler = createCompiler({
      appName,
      config,
      devSocket,
      urls,
      useYarn,
      useTypeScript,
      webpack,
    });
```

Inspect `config` you can see it created from `configFactory`

```
const config = configFactory('development');
```

Check `configFactory` you can see it is a function return server configuration as an object include property named `output`.

```
output: {
    ...
    filename: isEnvProduction
        ? 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js'
        : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/bundle.js',
      // TODO: remove this when upgrading to webpack 5
      futureEmitAssets: true,
      // There are also additional JS chunk files if you use code splitting.
      chunkFilename: isEnvProduction
        ? 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.js'
        : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
}
```

Here is what you are looking for.

Comment: How do you remove the static folder?